# Electric range only getting 120v

Tags: electrical, wiring, appliances

I have a Frigidaire electric range that isn't working properly, at least that's what I thought the problem was. Please excuse me while I detail me taking the long way to figure things out. I will preface this by saying that I am in the appliance repair field, but electrics were never my forte.

The stove gets power enough to run the lights and timer, but no heat in the oven nor the top burners so it's safe to assume it's only getting 120v from the outlet. I had a warranty company come out (not voiding my warranty just because I can), and they issued a new control board without testing anything. That's fine, I'll take a new control board for when this one fails. The problem is not the stove.

At this point, I have replaced the 40A breaker and the outlet both and still not getting the full 240 I need to operate the stove. I thought for sure either rod those would fix the problem. I'm at the end of my rope here as far as knowing what to try next.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any other 240 devices in your home? How are they doing? We regularly hear of a leg being dropped by the power company's equipment. Have you checked voltage at the panel?

Comment: Electricity is kind of basic.  You get 120/240 going into the wires at the breaker and it should come out at the outlet.  If it does not, then you have a broken wire somewhere or a bad connection.

Comment: `Electricity is kind of basic.` :O

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? If not, get one (CAT II minimum, UL or ETL listed). Then check the power to see what you get between the two hots.

Comment: The only other 240 appliance in the house is the dryer and that is working fine. I have not checked the voltage at the panel, and yes I do have a multimeter.

Comment: ***UPDATE*** I have tested at the panel and the breaker is providing 240. The stove is the only device on the breaker.

Comment: Have you checked the wall behind the stove? Have you checked the voltages at the connection bock on the back of the stove? You should be able to find the place the connection is broken. Is it plugged into a wall receptacle or is it hardwired?

Comment: Jim, I have checked the wall behind the stove. The outlet is the only place that is showing the incorrect voltage, so I figured replacing the outlet would do the trick. That did not work.

Comment: That leaves you with a broken wire between the breaker and outlet.  If you have the wires in conduit, then the multimeter will find the wire to pull.  If cable you will probably want to replace the whole cable.